# Can SourceSafe be configured to update AsemblyInfo

Tags: assemblies, visual-sourcesafe, assemblyversionattribute, assemblyversions

At work we have an (reasonable) agreement, that every time a project is updated, no matter how small change is, that is reflected in the Revision value of Assembly Information. This way we always know if a client is missing a patch or a feature, etc.

Since this requires manually changing the version, and since this is a tedious task (and worse, it can be forgotten) I was wondering if Visual SourceSafe (6 if it matters) could be configured so it would automatically update assembly version on every checkout / checkin ?

Is there an alternative / better option of maneging assembly versions?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at CruiseControl.NET. This is a continuous integration server that does the building for you, and can perform a number of other tasks for you as well, like update version numbers, run unit tests, code coverage analysis etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a build server you should configure your build server to auto increment the build/revision number with each build.